# Delphi 2007 and Indy10 compile error in IdGlobal

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, indy10

I've just updated my Indy10 installation to the latest revision (5260) and I now get an error when trying to compile a Windows service that receives emails from an email server.

> [DCC Error] IdGlobal.pas(8657): F2084 Internal Error: C4963

Reverting back to revision 5239 doesn't cause an issue.

The issue seems to be in `IdGlobal.ReadLnFromStream` on line 8633:

```
LBufSize := ReadTIdBytesFromStream(AStream, LBuf, LBufSize);
```

I'm wondering if this is a 64-bit issue, has anyone else encountered this issue? I'm using Delphi 2007 on Windows 7 Professional x64.

Comment: FYI, line 8633 is `LBufSize := IndyMin(LStrmSize - LStrmPos, LBUFMAXSIZE);` The line you quoted is line 8634 instead. So which line is the actual problem? The only thing I can think of is that both lines do involve Integer<->Int64 conversions, but I can't imagine the compiler choking on that, especially if it was working previously.

Comment: But either way, although there have been a lot of changes to `IdGlobal.pas` in the past 2 months (mostly in preparation for iOS 64bit), none of the changes should be affecting `ReadLnFromStream()` like this. But this is an **internal error**, which means anything could potentially be putting the compiler into a bad state even before it reaches `ReadLnFromStream()`. I don't have D2007 installed, so I can't troubleshoot the problem myself.  If you can narrow down a fix, you can send it to me for checkin.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the error still occur if you change this line: `LBufSize := IndyMin(LStrmSize - LStrmPos, LBUFMAXSIZE);` to this: `LBufSize := Integer(IndyMin(LStrmSize - LStrmPos, LBUFMAXSIZE));`? Or change `ReadTIdBytesFromStream()` to use `Integer` instead of `TIdStreamSize`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - the LBufsize is declared as integer, ReadTIdBytesFromStream expects a TIdStreamSize, but calls a class method which expects integer. I think I was looking at 8634, changing the LBufSize to TIdStreamSize fixed it, apologies for any mistakes, I'm now going off memory and the earliest I can do additional testing is Monday morning.

Comment: `TIdStreamSize` is `Int64` in D6+. A dynamic array uses `NativeInt` for its length and indexing, so `Integer` on 32-bit systems and `Int64` on 64-bit systems. But `TStream.Read()` uses `Longint` for its byte count and `Longint` is 32-bit on most platforms (iOS 64bit is changing that). So maybe `ReadLnFromStream()` needs to declare `LBufSize` as `NativeInt` to match the RTL and avoid unnecessary conversions, even though only 2K are being read at a time? I see some other functions in IdGlobal that are using `TIdStreamSize` where `NativeInt` might make more sense.

Comment: Some days ago I also had a internal compiler (c5242) in IdGlobal.pas(8661) with a new Indy revision (5254). It disappeared when I deleted and re-created the .proj file. I have not done further investigation about which change in the .proj caused the error. Maybe recreating the project helps here too.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Changing LBufSize local variable in IdGlobal.ReadLnFromSTream to TIdStreamStize gives a "types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical" when trying to call the nestsed function FindEOL (whose 2nd param is an Integer. The issue seems to be when passing a variable of TIdStreamSize as a parameter typed as Integer - the error message depends on whether the parameter is const or var.

Comment: @SteB: Obviously, the inner `FindEOL()` function would have to be updated to match whatever data type `LBufSize` is actually using.

Comment: @RemyLebeau would you consider checking in the change below?

Comment: @MikeT: it has been checked in, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know when and why this changed but I have the same issue (Delphi 2007). it appears that ReadTIdBytesFromStream is expecting an int64 (TIdStreamSize) to be passed as the Count parameter but the variable being passed (LBufSize) is an integer.

This appears to cause the complier considerable problems and it throws an internal error. I browsed around the Indy code until I found other examples of this function call that generated no errors.

I found this snippet of code in the TIdHashIntf.GetHashBytes method and borrowed from it

```
 repeat
   LSize := ReadTIdBytesFromStream(AStream,LBuf,IndyMin(ASize, 2048));
```

I then changed the code in ReadLnFromStream from this:

```
repeat
  LBufSize := IndyMin(LStrmSize - LStrmPos, LBUFMAXSZE);
  LBufSize := ReadTIdBytesFromStream(AStream, LBuf, LBufSize);
```

to this

```
repeat
  LBufSize := ReadTIdBytesFromStream(AStream, LBuf, IndyMin(LStrmSize - LStrmPos, LBUFMAXSIZE));
```

And now Indy builds and complies again.

As far as I can tell this change will not effect anything (apart from fixing the broken build), but I can appreciate it is a bit of a WTF. Without going deep into the reasons as to why some variables are int, others int64 and yet others are TIdStreamSize, this is the best I can do. Maybe Remy could enlighten us all.

Incidentally I noticed if complied in debug mode the fatal complier error did not occur.

Comment: This change has been checked in to Indy's SVN.